# d3 v4 select behaves differently when using a var

Tags: d3.js

For some reason, these two code blocks behave differently for their children on the first run:

```
var date = this.svg.selectAll(".date")
  .data(data);
date
  .enter()
  ...
```

and

```
var date = this.svg.selectAll(".date")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  ...
```

In the first example, the subsequent `date.selectAll(".bar").data(d => d.animal).enter;` has no items in `.enter`, whereas in the second example, there are items (but the subsequent updates don't work correctly). The even stranger thing is that if I just run the broken block twice, both of my problems are fixed.

When I use the variable, the `_groups` property is an empty array with the right length (placeholders?). When I chain functions without the variable, the `_groups` property is an array with the expected elements bound to data. I expected the binding to be done by the end of this block either way, but it's not.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinfunk/vvag4ycs/3/)

*Side note: if you can help with the animation to start at the bottom only on `.enter`, that would be incredible*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selections in d3 v4 are immutable](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#selections-d3-selection). This means that the subselections (to create the rectangles) are:

1: Never operating on the Entered elements

```
let date = svg.selectAll(".date").data(data);
// date selection/subselections don't contain entered elements
date.enter();
// date selection/subselections STILL don't not contain entered elements
```

2: Operating on only the Updated parent elements the first time, which are none

```
let date = svg.selectAll(".date").data(data).enter();
// date selection contains entered, but not updated elements
```

### Solution

I had to reassign the variable used, and merge the parent selection, even though I wasn't doing anything with the Updates from it. Personally I find this pattern to be a little more confusing than v4, and the documentation not giving a great example of this pitfall. It's also awkward to need to assign the variable before/during the `.enter` just so that you can merge in the Updated elements.

```
var date = svg.selectAll(".date")
  .data(data);
date = date
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "date")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${xScale0(d.date)},0)`)
.merge(date);
// date is now a selection that contains both the entered and updated elements
```

Fixed bars: https://jsfiddle.net/vvag4ycs/4/

Fixed bars & animation: https://jsfiddle.net/vvag4ycs/5/